# How to add data attributes to view list <li> tags?

Tags: 7, views

I have a HTML-list view, which generates `li` tags for my content. I want to add a `data-` attribute to each list item dependent on the content. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Override **style output** template file using theme information in views.....

[image]

Override file with below code..

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * - $title : The title of this group of rows.  May be empty.
 * - $options['type'] will either be ul or ol.
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php print $wrapper_prefix; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $list_type_prefix; ?>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
      <li data-attr="" class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php print $list_type_suffix; ?>
<?php print $wrapper_suffix; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what to do when the attribute is dependent on the content?